# temporarily disabling a function as2 flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am making a little platforming game for fun and have some simple jump code and i wanted to see if i could make my char double jump however what happens is when i try to press the button to jump up it triggers twice very quickly meaning that it only looks like a single jump instead of the 2 jumps, here is my current code

```
onClipEvent (load) {
    var ground:MovieClip = _root.ground;
    var grav:Number = 0;
    var gravity:Number = 2;
    var speed:Number = 10;
    var maxJump:Number = -14;
    var jumps:Number = 0;
}
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    _y += grav;
    grav += gravity;
    while (ground.hitTest(_x, _y, true))
    {
        _y -= gravity;
        grav = 0;
    }
    if (ground.hitTest(_x, _y + 5, true))
    {
        jumps = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        touchingGround = false;
    }
    if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT))
    {
        _x += speed;
    }
    if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT))
    {
        _x -= speed;
    }
    if (Key.isDown(Key.UP) && jumps>0)
    {
        grav = maxJump;
        jumps -= 1
        trace(jumps)
    }
    if (ground.hitTest(_x + (_width / 2), _y - (_height / 2), true))
    {
        _x -= speed;
    }
    if (ground.hitTest(_x - (_width / 2), _y - (_height / 2), true))
    {
        _x += speed;
    }
    if (ground.hitTest(_x, _y - (height), true))
    {
        grav = 3;
        if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT))
        {
            gotoAndPlay(1);
            if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT))
            {
                gotoAndPlay(2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sorry if everything isn't done right first quesiton of stack overflow thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

well, if the jumps variable(2) assigned to times, some function will be called, you should make function

> jump

to be like concatenating current _y to some jump height value (that way and only will be possible double jump).

Put all the code up there .. would be interesting to review it.